# Company size bug in job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently all job postings, under the "About this job" section, show company sizes that range from a number to 0.

Examples:

Company size: **11-0 people**
Company size: **501-0 people**
Company size: **1k-0 people**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were fixing some allocations earlier today and inadvertently introduced this bug. Thank you @TGO for spotting it! It should be fixed now.

Comment: Looks good. Have a nice day :)